# Are there datasheets for this dataflash memory?

Tags: memory, flash, datasheet

It's hard to read what is written on this dataflash memory but it looks like 25p80vg. I searched for datasheets and found some things similar to it, but couldn't find anything that matched it exactly. Are there datasheets for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data sheet i used to answer your other question is http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/181475/WINBOND/W25P80VFIG.html

The last to letters (VG) are voltages And packaging information

Comment: Why does is there an FI in between those letters?

Comment: it all depends on what the chip was used for or who it was manufactured for.