# Trying to understand this table in a datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I'm trying to understand this table in a datasheet:

[image]

Next to "Byte 2" there is a (5). What does that mean?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/11440/are-there-datasheets-for-this-dataflash-memory

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the (5) is a badly typeset footnote.